# linked horizontal scales in interactive VConcatChart?

Tags: python, altair

I can put multiple `interactive()` charts in a `VConcatChart`, but how do I define them so that the horizontal scale extent is the same in all the charts when interacting with one of them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make certain that the selection object that is used for interaction is the same within each sub-chart. There are a few ways to ensure this, but the easiest is to call `interactive()` only once in a base chart, and then modify that base chart for each panel of the plot.

For example:

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

cars = data.cars()

chart = alt.Chart(cars).mark_point().encode(
    x='Horsepower',
    color='Origin'
).interactive()

alt.vconcat(
    chart.encode(y='Miles_per_Gallon'),
    chart.encode(y='Acceleration')
)
```

[image: two-panel scatter]